# Why won't my oil burning water heater come back on?

Tags: boiler

I have a Buderus hot water boiler with domestic hot water. It only comes on if I push the reset on the burner, comes up to temp and shuts off as it should. It happened a few times a couple of weeks ago then it ran properly. Yesterday it started again and now it won't come without pushing the reset each time.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Time to call your oil burner service tech. I don't consider an oil burner as DIY territory, partly because every location I've ever lived in doesn't and requires a license to work on them, and the insurance companies tend to agree...

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll please take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer site, not a "general statement" site. I edited your question to actually, you know, ask a question. If I didn't quite get the gist right, please feel free to [edit] it again to clarify. As much as I'm all for DIY, I do, however, agree with @Ecnerwal, that it's probably best to call in a qualified service tech.

Comment: In my location I cannot even buy an accessory part for an oil burner, had to tell them it was for something else.  Advice given by an licensed contractor that was doing the work.

Comment: While you're waiting for the oil burner tech to show up, you can check to see if the CAD cell is covered in soot, and clean it if so. If it can't see the flame clearly, the burner will cut off after a short time and will require a reset.

Comment: Where is the CAD cell located

Comment: use a multimeter to track through each safety device until you find the one that isn't allowing the current to flow.